# Can I use a transformer to drop a DC voltage?

Tags: voltage-regulator, transformer, generator

Can I use a transformer to drop down the voltage from a generator? Or should I just use a regulator? The generator outputs about 9.3 V and I need about 5 V, and I want to conserve power.

Comment: dropping voltage won't "conserve power". total power output won't change, except you'll waste some in the conversion.

Comment: I want to waste the least amount of power in the conversion. Since I'm dropping the voltage can I get more current with a regulator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use a voltage regulator.**

A switching voltage regulator will be the most efficient. Texas Instruments [has a decent selection](http://www.ti.com/lsds/ti/power-management/step-down-buck-converter-products.page?#p634min=-0.8;5), just input the parameters you need.

A linear regulator would work too, but will not be as efficient as a buck topology.

A transformer will not work at all. Transformers are for alternating currents, not direct currents (AC vs. DC).

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing its DC. So a Transformer won't work. 
A Regulator will have to be used. Using a 7805 voltage regulator will do the trick.
If you want to conserve power, I think you can also just use a switching regulator -  Buck converter.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way will be using a linear voltage regulator. I personally used LP2950 from Texas Instrument to drop from 9V to 5V. 
Goodluck.